# jstree: Disable Multiple selection on root node only

Tags: jstree

How do you disable Multiple selection in jsTree only in root level?

Adding the code multiple: true, will disable multiple selection for my entire tree. But what I need is that it be disabled only in the root level.

Answer (score 0):

Use get_node(data.selected[0]), to assign only one node.